# How to add Table Of Content to docx output (adoc -> docbook -> docx)

Tags: pandoc, asciidoc, asciidoctor

I've created a simple document with the `:toc:` statement, but in the final file the table of content is missing.

```
:toc:

== bla bla

lorem inpsum....
```

And here are two commands I'm using to generate the docx file:

```
asciidoctor -r asciidoctor-diagram -b docbook5 index.adoc
pandoc -r docbook -t docx -o Document.docx index.xml --highlight-style espresso
```

Is there any way to add the `toc`?

I'm using the newest version of asciidoctor

Comment: `pandoc --toc` ?

Comment: Works fine, thanks